# do you know any editor with quick removal of eols in text

Tags: editors

I cant work out step 2 what I believe must be simple task in Linux

1. copy chunk of text in firefox (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
2. paste to and quickly remove eols globally in editor (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>'remove all eols', <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
3. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste it to Libre Calc cell

I know I can do it in vi with `%s/\n/` or any other 'Find and replace' but this is too much typing...

I quite like vi, atom and komodo edit but I am opened to something new too.

Thanks in advance

xi100f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a **mapping** in vi that pastes your text from clipboard, removes all EOLs and yanks it back to system clipboard. So it's possible to do your whole step 2 with a single mapping, leading two let's say two keypresses.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain how a mapping is done in vi.

Comment: @terdon: Don't you think it is okay to just hint someone in a direction and not give an exact solution and thereby not doing all their work for them? Also note that xi100f seems to know vi at least a bit, so this might be enough to answer his question. I am happy to delete my answer, cause I don't want to invest that extra time for figuring out the exact mapping here.

Comment: thanks cbaumhardt, I should be OK with  picking it up from there!

Comment: woud +1 your solution but not have enough reputation points...

Comment: That's ok, I'm not doing it for reputation. Glad I could help :)

Comment: @cbaumhardt I just suggested how you could improve your answer. Yes, the OP here seems to know vi, but maybe the next person to come along won't. We generally try to make our answers as comprehensive as possible here, and always aim to help future visitors and not only the person asking the specific question. Of course you shouldn't delete, it just seems a shame to give a mediocre answer when you could have given a good one.

Comment: quickly mapped '=' to find and replace `:map = :%s/\n/`

Answer (score 1):

What worked best for me was, as for cbaumhardt suggestion, mapping search and replace in vi:

`:map = :%s/\n/<CR>` and writing it to `~/.vimrc`.

Adding `<CR>` at the end of command saves pressing enter, so in total one key stroke is required to remove all eols.

If you do not like '=' as a shortcut check complete vi key bindings list and choose any other available character or combination.

Answer (score 0):

How about executing `vim` with a command to modify the clipboard and quit it again? This way you can map it to a key in your desktop environment and don't need to start anything manually.

All you need is to execute on a key binding on your favorite desktop environment:

`vim -c 'normal "+pggVGgJV"+yy' -c 'q!'`